# how to send image to server with other data in formdata in flutter

Tags: flutter, multipartform-data, dio, flutter-image-picker

is there any mistake while sending the data?

Image path is received correctly however the image is mandatory and not uploading

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import 'package:real_estate_app/domain/core/api_end_points.dart';

class APIAddService {
  static final Dio _dio = Dio();

  static Future<void> addProperty({
    required String accessToken,
    required String propName,
    required String propPrice,
    required String propAge,
    required int propStatus,
    required int propType,
    required String location,
    required int availabilityStatus,
    required List<String> spec,
    required List<String> size,
    required List<File> image,
  }) async {
    try {
      String apiUrl = ApiEndPoints.addproperty;

      List<MultipartFile> imageFiles = [];
      for (File img in image) {
        imageFiles.add(await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          img.path,
          filename: img.path.split('/').last,
        ));
      }

      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "prop_name": propName,
        "prop_price": propPrice,
        "prop_status": propStatus,
        "prop_type": propType,
        "prop_age": propAge,
        "location": location,
        "availability_status": availabilityStatus,
        "spec": spec,
        "size": size,
        "image": imageFiles,
      });
      log('imageFiles:$imageFiles');
      log('images: ${image.map((file) => file.path).toList()}');
      log('FormData: $formData');
      log('formfields:${formData.fields}');
      
      Options options = Options(headers: {
        "access-token": accessToken,
      });

      Response response = await _dio.post(
        apiUrl,
        data: formData,
        options: options,
      );

      print("Response status code: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response data: ${response.data}");

      if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.data['responseCode'] == 200) {
        print("Property added successfully!");
      } else {
        print("Failed to add property. Response data: ${response.data}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is DioException) {
        print("Dio Error: ${e.message}");
        print("Dio Error Response: ${e.response?.data}");
      } else {
        print("Error: $e");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what is the right way to do it?
I used the image_picker package to select multiple images, and then utilized Dio for sending server requests to upload them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to specify the content type ,use below snippet instead

```
List<MultipartFile> imageFiles = [];
      for (File img in image) {
        String fileName = basename(img.path);
        String fileExtension = extension(fileName).substring(1);
        imageFiles.add(await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          img.path,
          contentType: MediaType('image', fileExtension),
          filename: fileName,
        ));
      }
```